# Make cells in datagridTextColumn text columns appear as hyperlinks

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, hyperlink

I'm looking for the simplest way to make text in the cells of a dataGridTextColumn appear as hyperlinks, ie; blue, underlined.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to use a template column for this.  [See here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/48474.aspx) for more details on a possible solution.

**EDIT**

oh, I thought you needed a HyperLink column.  I would assume that you would need a combination of the text-decoration="underline" and foreground="blue" on your textBlock areas.  Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010%28VS.95%29.aspx) to see if you can get started with it...

Comment: I was hoping to not have to go this route, as all I need is the appearance, not the functionality.  I was hoping to just use styling, which is not my strong suit.